# Can a local Java program start jobs remotely via SSH using DRMAA?

Tags: java, ssh, hpc, drmaa

How does DRMAA work? Can a local Java program using DRMAA start jobs on a remote cluster over SSH (so that nothing will need to be installed on the server-side)?

**Background:**
I'm developing a general (or as general as possible) HPC client in Java/Eclipse RCP, and 
wanted to use DRMAA in order to support any resource manager as backend.

I have the SSH connection functionality through the Remote System Explorer (RSE) Eclipse plugin already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the DRMAA implementations use the native API calls (the same which are used inside the qsub/bsub/sbatch... commands). One can see DRMAA as the "ODBC for the batch systems".

Most of the DRMAA implementations require you to run it from submit host of your local cluster, there is no SSH inside. What you can try to do is to build a portable, DRMAA based "drmaa-run" command (example: http://apps.man.poznan.pl/trac/drmaa-misc/browser/drmaa_utils/trunk/drmaa_utils/drmaa_run.c) and run it via SSH.